# Argument/Parameter to start java game (.jar file) as maximized window

Tags: batch, java, window, jar

Im playing game called Spiral Knights
I launch .jar file with this batch command and portable java

```
CD "App"
"E:\Programy\Portable Apps Platform\PortableApps\CommonFiles\Java64\bin\java.exe" -Xms3G -Xmx3G -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -jar getdown-pro.jar .
exit
```

My question is does any argument or parameter (or whatever its called) exist to start game in maximized window? Not full screen just maximized

I am 2nd hour googling and trying stuff i found and stuff like

```
start /max or window=max
```

does not work

As i understand it all that arguments/parameters like start /max or window=max
are going to affect CMD window and not java app and thats why they dont work but all that

-Xms3G -Xmx3G -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC

affect java app so is there something like that for window maximized?

Comment: is this the same [jar file](http://gamemedia.spiralknights.com/spiral/client/getdown-pro.jar)? [In this link/site](https://forums.spiralknights.com/en/node/106526)

Comment: Exactly since this is the game im talking about
But i believe it could also be minecraft.jar

Since i seen same arguments/parameters are used to launch each of them when i find any script for Spiral Knights or Minecraft

Comment: I’ll try some possible way to do this...

Comment: Where I can find the same app portable?

Comment: You need to make it portable. But i think you mean launching it with batch script
Here https://www.spiralknights.com on right side under play now you have download button. Just download and then install it and you should get shortcut to SK on your desktop. Right click it > properties > open folder/file location.
Here all you need is batch script with (
More or less you need to adjust java path): 
Where if you have java installed then "%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xincgc -Xmx1G -jar getdown-pro.jar .

Comment: Or if you want to actually make it portable you will need portable java i get mine from here https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/OpenJDKJRE64
And then you will need to alter the pat for batch script

Comment: I think spiral knights installs to app data so after installation you can open any folder and type %APPDATA% into address bar and hit enter and you should see Spiral Knights folder there which you can move to desktop or wherever